# Getting error on ng serve: ERROR in Cannot read property 'listLazyRoutes' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular-cli

When running `ng serve` in command-line for an angular-cli generated project, I am getting error below:

```
 ERROR in Cannot read property 'listLazyRoutes' of undefined
```

Any thoughts on how to fix this error?

Answer (score 15):

Update angular-cli to latest: npm install -g angular-cli@latest

And in my particular case, I updated the package.json to this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.4.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.3.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.24",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "4.0.13",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "^4.0.2",
    "typescript": "~2.0.3",
    "webdriver-manager": "10.2.5"
  }
```

Perform npm install with this package.json content and it'll work.

Comment: Hi, this didn't work for me, any chance you got a sec to take a look at my question here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42419964/module-build-failed-typeerror-cannot-read-property-newline-of-undefined

Answer (score 5):

I was able to fix the issue by upgrading the angular-cli generated project to `angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.24`. If you generated the project from previous version (eg. *-beta.22 in my case), upgrade the local project package(dev dependencies) by running commands below:

```
>rm -rf node_modules dist tmp
>npm install --save-dev angular-cli@latest
>npm install
>ng init
```

To upgrade to new angular-cli, run commands below in the command-line:

```
>npm uninstall -g angular-cli
>npm cache clean
>npm install -g angular-cli@latest
```

Update on 2/23/2017: Syntax changed in getting latest angular-cli. Use command below instead:

`npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest`

Comment: I just did these steps exactly. They are the same steps [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli). It didn't fix the problem, though the other answer didn't work for me either, but it did once before. I'm stumped.

Comment: I was getting the same error but the app worked fine. Clean re-installing the cli(as mentioned above) seems to resolve the error message.

Comment: Hi I tried your fix, however still running into this error :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42419964/module-build-failed-typeerror-cannot-read-property-newline-of-undefined

Comment: just lately, the syntax change in updating latest angular-cli. Can you try this new syntax? `npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest`

Comment: That still didn't work for me :( luckly I had another (couple days older) Angular2 project, I copied it's package.json and I have my project working again. I'm guess at some point `@angular/cli@latest` will work for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42419964/module-build-failed-typeerror-cannot-read-property-newline-of-undefined/42422029#42422029

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me
[ERROR in Cannot read property 'listLazyRoutes' of undefined](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3758)

But I also needed to re install my @angular/core

Comment: _Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline._

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error :

> An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot read property 'B' of
> undefined.

So I updated my `angular cli`, core and compiler version using :

```
ng update
```

Then I installed the latest `node.js LTS` version from [here](https://nodejs.org/en/)  which solved my issue.