# Angular CLI stopped working - Unexpected token {

Tags: angular, build, npm

I used Angular CLI to create projects for a while and it was working fine. But when I tried to create a new project today I got an error when trying to serve it.

```
ng serve
Unexpected token {
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
   at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
   at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
   at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
   at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
   ...
```

Here is the full stack trace http://pastebin.com/71qU3G64

If I delete the node_modules directory and copy it from an old project it works, but that is not a long term solution.

Comment: Use `ng -v` and `npm -v` in the console and post it here.

Comment: ng -v
Unexpected token {

npm 3.10.9

http://pastebin.com/JyHmY2JR

Comment: If even the `ng -v` command doesn't work for you, I suggest you to reinstall `angular-cli`.

Comment: It seems like the first issue is impacting the ng -v problem. If I restart the cmd I get ng -v

angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.19-3
node: 4.5.0
os: win32 x64

Comment: Fine. Update your `node` first to the version of 6.9 or higher.

Comment: try reinstalling the node_modules

Comment: Updated node which got rid of the original problem, but now I get a error with Jasmine instead, please see http://pastebin.com/CqG5Les2

Comment: Tried reinstalling node_modules, no difference

Comment: Also if I replace the @types directory with an old node_modules one it works without the Jasmine error. But once again this is not a long term solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is now working after

- Updating node as suggested by Kind user
- Updating Angular CLI https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli

For my old project to work after these changes I had to do the following (some of the steps are from the link above).

- rmdir /s node_modules
- rmdir /s dist
- npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
- npm install
- ng update
- Update package.json as suggested here [Getting error on ng serve: ERROR in Cannot read property 'listLazyRoutes' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41359642/getting-error-on-ng-serve-error-in-cannot-read-property-listlazyroutes-of-und)
- npm install (again)

This update worked for most of my projects but I still have an issue with one

```
ng serve
  patterns.map is not a function
  TypeError: patterns.map is not a function
  at GlobCopyWebpackPlugin.apply (C:\Users\jhertz\Workspaces\eclipsekatujo\ibi\src\app\node_modules\@angular\cli\plugins\glob-copy-webpack-plugin.js:25:29)
  at Compiler.apply (C:\Users\jhertz\Workspaces\eclipsekatujo\ibi\src\app\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:306:16)
  at webpack (C:\Users\jhertz\Workspaces\eclipse-katujo\ibi\src\app\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js:32:19)
  at Class.run (C:\Users\jhertz\Workspaces\eclipse-katujo\ibi\src\app\node_modules\@angular\cli\tasks\serve.js:63:27)
  at checkExpressPort.then.then (C:\Users\jhertz\Workspaces\eclipse-katujo\ibi\src\app\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\serve.js:84:26)
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
```

The above error got solved by updating the angular-cli.json in the project folder.

```
== Old ==
"assets": "assets",
== New ==
"assets": ["assets"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Experienced the same problem but I managed to solve it by deleting the node_modules folder and the yarn.lock file. I then re-installed the packages (using yarn) and changed the node version to >=8.9.0, and it worked.