# ng-serve constructor error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, npm

I am working on an Angular js application. While trying to run the dev server, i am getting an error with my [ng serve](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/serve) constructor:

[image]

Comment: what is your node.js version? Instead of image link, i would recommend to copy the error and paste it in question.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please give us a **[Minimum, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** so that we can help you with your problem. Also please take time to read more about our site through both the **[tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)** and **[help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)**

Comment: Hi, I edited your question. I Made it more succinct, added the image to the question instead of a link, and added a link to ng-serve which is what "I think" you're talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without being able to see your code (most likely you forgot something small or misspelled something), I would recommend you **update Node**. There are other questions about `unexpected token` errors, and the solution is usually to update Node and/or Angular-CLI. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42175354/1152809) and [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5150).