# Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'newLine' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

[image]

Everything was running fine yesterday, now when I try to ng serve I get these errors:

> ERROR in ./src/main.ts
>   Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'newLine' of undefined
>       at Object.getNewLineCharacter (/Users/leongaban/Projects/TickerTags/wikitags/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:8062:20)

I tried the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41359642/getting-error-on-ng-serve-error-in-cannot-read-property-listlazyroutes-of-und) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42128715/angular-2-typescript-cannot-read-property-newline-of-undefined) but no effect :(

My global and local npm version for **angular-cli** is `1.0.0-beta.28.3` how do I upgrade that to .30? I tried `@latest`

---

My local package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0-beta.28.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.0",
```

---

My global package:

[image]

---

I see that the latest is beta.32 https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/releases

However when I run `npm install -g angular-cli@latest` it still installs `.28.3`

Comment: Strangely I could fix this by deleting the `node_modules` folder and then reinstall everything.

Comment: Does `ng -v` return the same package for local and global?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In package.json I changed:

```
"devDependencies": {
   "@angular/cli": "1.0.0"
```

To:

```
"devDependencies": {
   "@angular/cli": "1.2.0"
```

Answer (score 2):

OS : Windows with Angular 4

"@angular/cli": "1.2.1"

"@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.6"

I just removed the caret from above two dependencies and performed following steps, everything started working perfectly.

1. Remove node_module
2. Uninstall angular cli from local and global
3. Install the same version of angular cli in both
4. Do "npm install"
5. "ng serve"

Answer (score 0):

They've moved to `@angular/cli` package name, to comply with the other `@angular` modules. To be sure you are not left with old files, perform the following steps:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

then remove your local `node_modules` folder and execute:

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
npm install
```

The latest angular cli version is .32. There are still issues with upgrading to newer versions, but hopefully with the next update they will have that under control. If not, repeat the steps I just mentioned

Comment: Thanks, I did that... and I have `1.0.0-beta.32.3` in my global and local. Did `ng serve` again, and had to do a small update in my `angular-cli.json` file. Ran ng serve again and still getting this error :( I guess I have to wait till the next version? Any files you need to see?

Comment: My `"@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.0",` is at that version, does that matter?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is:

```
diff --git a/angular-cli.json b/angular-cli.json
index d74d5d4..2641672 100644
--- a/angular-cli.json
+++ b/angular-cli.json
@@ -1,7 +1,7 @@
 {
   "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
   "project": {
-    "version": "1.0.0-beta.31",
+    "version": "1.0.0-beta.28",
     "name": "renaissance"
   },
   "apps": [
@@ -22,8 +22,8 @@
         "styles.less"
       ],
       "scripts": [],
+      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
       "environments": {
-        "source": "environments/environment.ts",
         "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
         "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
       }
diff --git a/package.json b/package.json
index b91db8f..7e2b083 100644
--- a/package.json
+++ b/package.json
@@ -12,13 +12,13 @@
   },
   "private": true,
   "dependencies": {
-    "@angular/common": "^2.4.0",
-    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.0",
-    "@angular/core": "^2.4.0",
-    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.0",
-    "@angular/http": "^2.4.0",
-    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.0",
-    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.0",
+    "@angular/common": "^2.4.8",
+    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.8",
+    "@angular/core": "^2.4.8",
+    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.8",
+    "@angular/http": "^2.4.8",
+    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.8",
+    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.8",
     "@angular/router": "^3.4.0",
     "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-alpha.20",
     "angularfire2": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
@@ -27,15 +27,14 @@
     "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
     "moment": "^2.17.1",
     "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.3.3",
-    "ng2-page-transition": "^0.2.6",
+    "ng2-page-transition": "^1.0.4",
     "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
     "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
     "web-animations-js": "^2.2.2",
     "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
   },
   "devDependencies": {
-    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0-beta.31",
-    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.0",
+    "@angular/cli": "^1.0.0-beta.32.3",
     "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
     "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
     "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
@@ -44,8 +43,8 @@
     "karma": "1.2.0",
     "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
     "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
-    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
     "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
+    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
     "protractor": "~5.1.0",
     "ts-node": "1.2.1",
     "tslint": "^4.3.0",
diff --git a/src/app/app.module.ts b/src/app/app.module.ts
index 1f862c6..b6568b7 100644
--- a/src/app/app.module.ts
+++ b/src/app/app.module.ts
@@ -8,7 +8,7 @@ import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
 // App modules/components
 import {LayoutsModule} from "./Components/common/layout/layout.module";
 import {BlochWidgetsModule} from "./Components/common/widgets/widgets.module";
-import {Ng2PageTransition} from "ng2-page-transition";
+import {Ng2PageTransitionModule} from "ng2-page-transition";
 //services
 import {PeopleHttpService} from "./Components/common/service/httpPeople.service";
 //auth Module
@@ -30,9 +30,9 @@ import {MessagingModule} from "./views/messaging/messaging.module";
 @NgModule({
   declarations: [
     AppComponent,
-    Ng2PageTransition,
   ],
   imports: [
+    Ng2PageTransitionModule,
     BrowserModule,
     FormsModule,
     HttpModule,
```

Comment: Can you explain this answer some?  Most of us aren't using a `PeopleHttpService`, or a `BlochWidgetsModule`.  What did you change to get your build to work, when before it was failing with the error?

Answer (score 0):

**This worked for me :-** 
`rm -rf node_modules && npm cache clean && npm uninstall --save angular-cli; npm uninstall -g angular-cli; npm i --save @angular/cli && npm i -g @angular/cli && npm i`

> rm -rf node_modules/ in your project to get rid of all npm stuff and then npm cache clean followed by npm install should also resolve this issue. Also, make sure the versions of the cli locally and globally match.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3781

Answer (score -1):

So none of the install @angular/cli@latest worked for me, most likely will work in the future I presume.

I had another angular2 project which was `ng serve`-ing fine. So I just copied the package.json dependencies from it and updated the angular-cli.json.

And now it works again!

#### package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "^3.4.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0-beta.31",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.0",
    "node-sass-import": "^1.1.1",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.1.6",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "^4.3.0",
    "typescript": "~2.0.0"
  }
```

#### angular-cli.json

Had to revert back to the older type of `"source"` key

```
"environments": {
    "source": "environments/environment.ts",
    "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
    "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
}
```

Comment: this is a nightmare of dev exp

Answer (score -1):

Just update to   "@angular/cli": "1.0.0-rc.0"   "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.0" in your package.json and update file angular-cli.json like below

change

```
"environments": {
    "source": "environments/environment.ts",
    "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
    "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
}
```

by

```
"environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
```